# jquery.load() not working in IE while loading html file from another port

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Code**

```
$('.form').load('http://'+window.location.hostname+':8423/html/form/form_generate.html/?session='+session);
```

- We are trying to load a html file from another port number in the same server.
- The original server is located at 8000 port.
- The users will access the application using the ipaddress and port no. for ex: 189.45.23.56:8000
- Firefox seems to be loading this fine.
- IE is neither throwing any error nor loading the file.
- After exploring a little bit, I came to know about the "cross origin policy".

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: If you are requesting same domain name with client, same origin policy should pass. What is exact error IE gives

Comment: Any idea what might be the problem because, neither IE throws any error nor it loads the file.

Comment: Same origin includes port, are you sure this is working on FF?

Comment: Can we test it? Any online link?

Comment: @A.Wolff  I regret to say that it is hosted in a server. It works only in my companies network. :(

Comment: This is against same origin policy - [An origin is defined by the scheme, host, and **port** of a URL](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy). I am surprised it works in Firefox

Comment: So enable CORS on server but again, i don't see why your current code would work on FF and not on IE. Test it on chrome too. I'm quite sure you are checking it in a wrong way or i'm missing something

Comment: @Peter Me too. Do you know any workaround for this in IE?

Comment: @A.Wolff  I tested it in the same way in the three browsers. Its working in Firefox as well as chrome but not in IE. :(

Comment: @user1787687 And no error in IE console (network tab), right?!

Comment: @A.Wolff In network tab, it don't even see the file loaded. I didn't see any errors also. No errors in the console as well.

Comment: @user1787687 I hope a network expert could help you more than i can, GL!

Comment: Hey - console.log this `'http://'+window.location.hostname+':8423/html/form/form_generate.html/?session='+session` the problem is not in same origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The problem seems to be a bug in jquery. We should add `$.support.cors = true;` to make cross domain requests work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know: Even another port is considered cross origin request. There are two quick workarounds coming into my mind right now:

1. Try to host both websites under the same port
2. Using JsonP to get the content cross origin

There was another way to allow cross origin access by alternate the settings of the webserver, but not sure how to do this excactly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried JsonP with no success. I am actually running two servers. So there is no way I can run the two websites on the same port :(  I guess the setting you are talking about is "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". Tried this also. Not working in Ie.